# ESLint - how to disable react/forbid-foreign-prop-types?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

in my Chrome console, I'm seeing the following warnings:

```
Module Warning (from /Users/me/sites/site/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):  

Line 365:16:  Using propTypes from another component is not safe because they may be removed in production builds  react/forbid-foreign-prop-types  

Line 365:45:  Using propTypes from another component is not safe because they may be removed in production builds  react/forbid-foreign-prop-types
```

Per the docs, I tried to disable this warning by adding the following to the top of the file causing the warning:

```
/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle, forbid-foreign-prop-types */
```

This is having no effect to silence the warning. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
/* eslint-disable react/forbid-foreign-prop-types */
```

Answer (score 0):

put this line into `.eslintrc`

```bash
"react/prop-types": 0
```